# Static IPv6 setup with netplan

Tags: networking, 22.04, netplan, wget, ipv6

After running in to upgrade issues (not able to retrieve https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts) I found out that my static IPv6 setup caused this issue.

However I'm stumped as how to fix it.

Using netplan with an automatically configured IPv6 gives me a working situation:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: true
            accept-ra: false
            addresses:
              - 192.168.234.12/24
            nameservers:
                search: [mydomain.com]
                addresses:
                  - 127.0.0.1
                  - 192.168.234.12
            routes:
              - to: default
                via: 192.168.234.1
```

Using this static setup:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            accept-ra: false
            addresses:
              - 192.168.234.12/24
              - 2a02:aabb:ccdd:1::12/64
            nameservers:
                search: [mydomain.com]
                addresses:
                  - 127.0.0.1
                  - 192.168.234.12
                  - ::1
                  - 2a02:aabb:ccdd:1::12
            routes:
              - to: default
                via: 192.168.234.1
              - to: default
                via: fe80::3ea6:2fff:fe44:f0bc
```

causes my testcase: `wget https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts` to fail. I.e. after the initial connect nothing happens.

I've already tried different options with extra routes added manually but nothing seems to work. So I hope someone here has some ideas.

Cheers,
Raz

Comment: What IPv6 prefix do you get from your ISP? Or asked differently: Who assigned you the prefix `2a02:aabb:ccdd:1::/64`? (It looks like this block has not even be assigned to any organization.) If you have chosen that address by yourself: You cannot just use any IPv6 block and expect others to have it routed to your network, like you cannot assign just any arbitrary IPv4 address to your router and expect it to work on the Internet.

Comment: The ```2a02:aabb:ccdd:1::``` is redacted for privacy purposes. My ISP assigned me a ```2a02:aabb:ccdd::/48``` prefix. I'm using the ```2a02:aabb:ccdd:1::/64``` in my network.

Comment: Please state in your question if any addresses are "redacted" (or just replace some digits with "x", so everyone can see it). That you have an assigned /48 is also important. Did you tell your router that it should route your chosen /64 to your LAN? Does your host get an address _in that /64_ when using DHCPv6?

Comment: Ok, sorry about the confusion. I wasn't aware of that convention. I didn't explicitly tell my Fritzbox router to choose /64 for my LAN. But yes, when using DHCPv6 I get an address in that /64 range ```inet6 2a02:xxxx:xxxx:1:be5f:f4ff:feb6:b823/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute valid_lft 7198sec preferred_lft 3598sec```